# JSF 1.1 Datatable CRUD operation

Tags: java, jsf, crud, tomahawk

We have a old application running with JSF 1.1, cannot upgrade due to client specification.

I would like to know is it possible to have a datatable with JSF 1.1 and upon clicking a button or link in datatable row open a dialog popup and do CRUD operation?

Thanks

Edit 1

I guess Apache Trinidad supports JSF 1.1. Can I do CRUD operation with Trinidad?

Comment: @subhrajyoti: please stop formatting non-code as code.

Comment: I also work on a JSF1.1 app for a client, and we use Tomahawk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using Richfaces 3.1.6 (JSF 1.1 compatible) with the great A4J, will help you doing so:

```
<h:form id="myForm">
<rich:dataTable width="100%" style="border:none;margin-left:15px;" id="tableId" columnClasses="colClass"
            value="#{managedBean.someList}" var="someVar">

    <h:column> some content for this column </h:column>
    <h:column>
           <a4j:commandLink styleClass="linkClass" value="Delete" reRender="myForm:myModal" ajaxSingle="true" oncomplete="#{rich:component('myForm:myModal')}.show()" actionListener="#{managedBean.someMethodToUpdateDTO}">
              <a4j:actionparam value="#{someVar.idForExample}" name="someName"  assignTo="#{managedBean.someDTOObjectToBeUpdated.id}"/>
           </a4j:commandLink>

    </h:column>
</rich:dataTable>

<rich:modalPanel id="panel" width="350" height="100">
    <f:facet name="header">
    <h:panelGroup>
        <h:outputText value="Are you really, really sure to delete this one!!! #{managedBean.someDTOObjectToBeUpdated.name}"></h:outputText>
    </h:panelGroup>
    </f:facet>
    <a4j:commandButton styleClass="btnClass" value="Oui" ajaxSingle="true" oncomplete="#{rich:component('myForm:myModal')}.hide()" reRedner="myForm:tableId" action="#{managedBean.deleteIt}">
</rich:modalPanel>

</h:form>
```

someMethodToUpdateDTO is a method, in your managed bean that looks like this:

```
public void someMethodToUpdateDTO(ActionEvent event){
    //In this method I just load the object from somewhere else
    someDTOObjectToBeUpdated = someDAO.getObject(someDTOObjectToBeUpdated.getId()); 
    //someDTOObjectToBeUpdated is an attribute of your managed bean, of course with its     getter and setter
}
```

Hope this helps,

Cheers

Comment: Thanks a lot Laabidi Raissi

Comment: I ran into a small problem though, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15582791/richfaces-theme-issue-and-datatable-style-class-issue

Comment: Sorry, I am very drunk by now, and you really don't want to ask me about Java (it's 4h in the morning in my country)

Comment: Don't mind, If your problem remains unsolved still tomorrow (after 10 hours from now) I will try to solve it